# alguien ha oido hablar de la API PSD2 para acceder a la información bancaria?

Tags: api

Se que esta pregunta es un poco difusa, pero llevo unos días buscando información en internet y no he visto una línea de código, por lo que no puedo poner nada de lo que tengo programado.

Desde este año se los bancos están trabajando con una normativa (api) llamada PSD2, una nueva forma de comunicacion-autentificacion, de modo que se permiten realizar pagos, consultar información de cuentas bancarias,etc.

Si teneis una aplicación en el móvil (no la de vuestro banco) que gestiona vuestras cuentas, os avisa de los cobros, cargos, gastos, etc usa esta tecnología.

En teoría, hay una API que permite realizar esta programación, pero llevo 4 días mirando, y no he visto ni una línea de codigo, ni en que lenguaje esta desarrollada esta API, ni como usarla.

Alguien sabe de alguna web o alguna pagina que diga al menos por donde empezar?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo único que te puedo decir es que preguntes en el foro de inglés, quizás ellos sepan más.

Comment: Pienso que ese tipo de especificaciones son propios de la normativa de cada país. En Chile las apps que hacen ese tipo de comunicación (estilo [Mint](https://www.mint.com/))  han tenido que construir un conector distinto para cada nuevo banco o institución crediticia que integran

Comment: Gracias a ambos. La directiva es a nivel de la Unión Europea

Comment: ¿? Por lo que sé, PSD2 establece que los bancos tienen que facilitar el acceso a terceros (con la autorización del titular) para que puedan hacer evaluaciones, sugerencias, etc. Pero no definen un API única, ni siquiera establecen que haya de ser via APIs.

Comment: Si eso es cierto que los bancos tienen que facilitar el acceso, de hecho hasta les interesa, pero lo que estoy estudiando ese mecanismo, si es una directiva común, vale que cada banco la implementara como quiera, pero dentro del estándar, pero como digo, es que no he visto nada, solo explicaciones de que es, para que sirve, etc.

Comment: no entiendo el porque los votos negativos, si alguien me lo puede explicar, estaría bien

Answer (score 0):

Hola he encontrado esto en github, te paso el enlace espero que te sirva. 
https://github.com/OpenBankProject/OBP-API/wiki/PSD2-Sandbox

Comment: Cuidado, que eso no tiene PARA NADA pinta de un proyecto oficial. Más bien parece una startup en plan "a ver si la idea busca y los bancos nos compran esto". Nótese que en ningún sitio, ni en tu enlace ni en https://www.openbankproject.com/, hace referencia a ningún banco que ofrezca esta API... No hay nada que indique que los bancos deban usar esa API o similar para cumplir con PSD2.

Comment: El busca información de por donde empezar.

Comment: Cualquier punto de partida, cualquiera información es válida, lo estoy mirando